# Pandas Merge with NaN values

Tags: python, pandas

I want to do: df1 LEFT JOIN df2 on `df1['B']=df2['B'] & df1['C']=df2['C']` OR `df1['B']=df2['B'] & df2['C'] IS NULL` OR `df2['B'] IS NULL & df1['C']=df2['C']`

Here's an example input and output:

df1:

```
| A | B | C |
|---|---|---|
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 5 | 6 | 7 |
```

df2:

```
|  B  | C   | D |
|-----|-----|---|
| 2   | 3   | 4 |
| NaN | 7   | 8 |
| 6   | NaN | 9 |
```

Output:

```
| A | B | C | D |
|---|---|---|---|
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 |
| 5 | 6 | 7 | 9 |
```

Comment: Good, now the only thing we miss is your attempt. Can yo share what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

I think we can do this in multiple steps, there is no functionality in pandas merge or join that will do this. However, this method should work.

```
df_b = df1.merge(df2, on='B', how='left', suffixes=('','_y'))[['A','B','C','D']]

df_c = df1.merge(df2, on='C', how='left', suffixes=('','_y'))[['A','B','C','D']]

pd.concat([df_b,df_c]).drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
   A  B  C  D
0  1  2  3  4
1  5  6  7  9
2  5  6  7  8
```